# JavaScript Remove Class if Date is between a Range

Tags: javascript, css, date

I have a code that removes a class if the date is between certain months.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var month = new Date().getMonth()+1;
if(month >=2 && month <=4){
 jQuery('.off-season-hours .mbhi-is-current').removeClass('mbhi-is-current');
}else{
 jQuery('.on-season-hours .mbhi-is-current').removeClass('mbhi-is-current');
}
});
</script>
```

But I need it to be narrowed down to February 1 to April 15.

Comment: You can get date from `Date()` and your condition could be `if(month == 1 || month == 2 || (month == 3 && date <= 15)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

So instead of using the month integer value for your range, use the Date itself

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var month = new Date().getMonth()+1;
var start = new Date("2018-2-1");
var end = new Date("2018-4-15");
if(month >=start && month <=end){
 jQuery('.off-season-hours .mbhi-is-current').removeClass('mbhi-is-current');
}else{
 jQuery('.on-season-hours .mbhi-is-current').removeClass('mbhi-is-current');
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use momentjs + twix

https://momentjs.com/docs/
http://isaaccambron.com/twix.js/

```
var range = moment("2018-02-01").twix("2018-04-15");
if(range.contains(moment())){
    //remove
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `getDate()` function built in.

```
var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
var date = new Date().getDate() + 1;

if((month >= 2 && month <= 3) || (month === 4 && date <= 15)) {... your code}
```

Basically, it covers the special case if it is April, it should check which day of the month is active so it could remove the class.

Comment: `getMonth() + 1` you probably missed this one

Comment: Yes, I missed that point. However I guess you mean `getDate()` not `getDay()` which returns day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

To tack onto ControlAltDel, if you're comparing specific dates, you don't need the month, you can just compare the date objects. Also, assuming you don't want to have to remember to come back and update this every year, you can dynamically select the current year too.

```
let today = new Date();
let offSeason = new Date(`${today.getFullYear()}-4-15`);
let onSeason = new Date(`${today.getFullYear()}-2-1`);

jQuery(`.${(today >=  onSeason && today <= offSeason ? 'on' : 'off')}-season-hours .mbhi-is-current`)
  .removeClass('mbhi-is-current');
```